# if $U$ is a real, orthogonal matrix with det(U)=1, and $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of $U$, then $U=(1-A)(1+A)^{-1}$ for a skew-symmetric $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

I was trying to prove that if $U$ is a real and orthogonal matrix with det(U)=1, and $-1$ is not an eigenvalue, then $U=(1-A)(1+A)^-1$ for a skew-symmetric $A$

I have been able to prove that, if $A$ is skew symmetric, then $U=(1-A)(1+A)^{-1}$ is an orthogonal matrix with determinant 1.

The only sensible matrix I can think of for $A$, is $A= U-U^T$, or perhaps $A= \frac{U-U^T}{2}$, but then I cannot see how the determinant or eigenvalue condition would be relevant; and when I tried muddling through it didn't lead anywhere.

thank you :)

Comment: Apologies, I mean that -1 isn't an eigenvalue of U

Comment: oh oops, thank you :)) in hindsight i should have spotted that!